# Are there more possibilities for having twin primes occurring than cousin primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Let any prime be $X$

It started out with an experiment to find out if there are some patterns in primes with $X \mod 6 = 1$ Versus primes with $X \mod 6 = 5$.

I have then checked to see what are the multiples of $6$ before getting the remainders and obviously some duplicates came in due to cousin primes, such as in the case of $27$ being the multiple: $(27 * 6) + 1= 163$ and $(27 * 6)+5=167$

But here is the thing:

All these multiples shared a limited set of possible endings, they can only end in either: $1,2,3,6,7,8$ and always excluding possible endings in 0,4,5,9

Let the multiple be $Y$

Below is a short example of the first hundreds of $Y$'s generated from  $(6 * Y)+1 = prime$ and $(6 * Y)+5 = prime$ while sharing the same $Y$ (I have further tested the first 10000):

Why are the endings limited to a limited amount of possible digits, and does it imply that in a probabilistic fashion, there are more possibilities for twin primes to occur than cousin primes?

[image]

Comment: Do you know modular arithmetic?

Comment: I understand the concept of it, as far as possible remainders, but how does it limit the possibility of ending digits ?

Comment: When you look at $6k+1 \pmod{10},$ it gives you the last digit of the number $6k+1,$  and because $6(k+5)+1 = 30 +6k +1 \equiv  6k+1 \pmod{10},$ the last digit is periodic of period $5,$ plugging in $k=0,1,2,3,4$ gives you all possible values. Similarly for $6k+5.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your first query, you ask why $Y$ cannot end in the digits $0,4,5,9$

Looking at cases, if $Y$ ends in $0,5$, then $6Y$ ends in $0$ and $6Y+5$ ends in $5$, yielding a number which is divisible by $5$ and hence not prime, so it can't be part of a pair of cousin primes.

Similarly, if $Y$ ends in $4,9$, then $6Y$ ends in $4$ and $6Y+1$ ends in $5$, yielding a number which is divisible by $5$ and hence not prime, so it can't be part of a pair of cousin primes.

There is a similar situation regarding twin primes. Consider twin primes of the form $6Z-1,\ 6Z+1$. You will find that $Z$ cannot end in $1,4,6,9$ for similar reasons. The argument for $4,9$ is the same as for the case of $Y$.

If $Z$ ends in $1,6$, then $6Z$ ends in $6$ and $6Z-1$ ends in $5$, yielding a number which is divisible by $5$ and hence not prime, so it can't be part of a pair of twin primes.

In both instances, there are $4$ forbidden end digits, so I don't think this would form a basis to argue a difference in the density of twin vs cousin primes.